 × 0 > 0 when  is the cardinality of real numbers in the real number line
Is there a flaw in the reasoning below that  × 0 > 0 when  is the cardinality of real numbers in the real number line?
The cardinality of any real number interval (0, r) for r > 0 is .

Thus, any interval (0, r), r > 0 has  numbers of real numbers.

Thus, the length of c numbers of real numbers is r, the length of an interval (0, r).

The length of each real number is 0 by Definition.

Thus, the length of  numbers of real numbers is expressed as  × 0.

Thus,  × 0 = r. r can be any real number > 0.

Thus,  × 0 > 0.■ 

If a unit length is divided by , the resulting segments are a point which has a length of 0.
Thus, 1/c = 0.
If a unit length is divided by a point which has a length of 0, the number of segments will be .
Thus, 1/0 = .
 is a concept that allows to create something from nothing ( × 0 > 0) and to annihilate something into nothing in reverse (1/ = 0), which is against the law of conservation in physics.
How baffling it may be, it is the very definition of .
Even though  is termed as the ‘cardinality’ of the set, the fact that  is a ‘counting number’ cannot be eluded because  is the result of ‘counting’ the number of elements in the set.
The symbol × in  × 0 is multiplication between ‘counting number’ and real number 0 in the real number line and not between cardinality.

I would argue that this line of reasoning doesn’t show that $\mathfrak{c} \cdot 0 > 0$, but rather that the expression $\mathfrak{c} \cdot 0$ as described in the argument isn’t well defined.

This is mixing up (rudiments of) cardinal arithmetic and measure theory into pretty much nonsense. Maybe one specific error is the misconception that the "length" of an interval would be the (uncountable) sum of all the lengths of the singletons, which is not true

As in the proof,  × 0 is  times the length of 0, or summing the length of 0 by  times.

I am not using the cardinal arithmetic and measure theory.
I am just rewriting the definition of .

Yup, flaw. The singleton set $\{x\}$ has measure $0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but that doesn't mean all arbitrary-sized unions of singleton sets have measure $0$. Measure only has countable additivity.
(Good grief what is wrong with the markup here. It displays differently in preview mode vs published! Sorry for the ASCII curly-braces rather than MathJax.)

You need to backslash curly braces, as they are part of the syntax of LaTeX. You might have also got bitten by the common problem of LaTeX not updating consistently in preview mode. Regardless, I did the edit to LaTeX in your post.

As long as we designed the concept of uncountable infinity, we may discuss uncountable additivity.

@user1286486 and the measure on the reals… is not uncountably additive.
